# Add Spatrastermap to existing Spatrastermap

Tags: r, ggplot2, terra, tidyterra

I would like to combine the map p with the map x in the following way:
at those points where the plot x is white, I would like to see plot p (as first layer), and for the colored points the plot x, as second layer.

```
f = system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r = rast(f)
p <- ggplot() + geom_spatraster_contour(data=r)
plot(p)
x = classify(r, cbind(-Inf, 400, NA))
plot(x)
```

Comment: I guess I'd wonder about the 'shift' leftish that appears with tidyterra::geom_spatraster_contour vs `plot(as.contour(r))`, `plot(x, add = TRUE)` as you might have noticed before worry about colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired output using `geom_spatraster_contour` and `geom_spatraster`. You just need to add the layers in order of appearance (first layers are plotted on the bottom and the last ones on top) and use one of the `scale_fill_*` functions to set the fill palette and define the NA color.

```
library(terra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)

ggplot() + 
  geom_spatraster_contour(data=r) +
  geom_spatraster(data = x, aes(fill = elevation)) + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(terrain.colors(10)),
                   na.value = "transparent") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: elevation data]

Comment: Great, thank you. Do you know how to preserve the original colors with red to green sprectrum?

Comment: Yeah, take a look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

With these data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
x <- classify(r, cbind(-Inf, 400, NA))
```

You can do

```
plot(as.contour(r))
plot(x, add=TRUE)
```

Or something like

```
plot(x)
cntr <- as.contour(r, add=TRUE)
plot(x, add=TRUE)
```